# Kernel and image of vector bundle morphism over smooth submersion.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

Suppose we have vector bundles $\pi_E:E\to M$ and $\pi_{E'}:E'\to M'$, smooth submersion $G:M\to M'$  and vector bundle morphism   $F:E\to E'$  over $G$. Are then the sets
$ker F$ and $im F$ smooth vector subbundles of  $E$ and $E'$.

I know that the answer is yes if $G=id_M$, however I am not sure what the answer is in this case. Can someone give me some literature with the proof please.

EDIT: I forgot to say that $F$ has a constant rang.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of $\operatorname{ker}(F)$, we can use the fact that $F$ factors uniquely through the [pullback bundle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pullback_bundle) $G^*E'$, i.e. there is a unique morphism $\widetilde{F}:E\to G^*E'$ over $\operatorname{id}_M$ such that the $H\circ\widetilde{F}=F$ where $H:G^*E'\to E'$ is the pullback map. Since $H$ is an isomorphism on fibers, $\widetilde F$ is constant rank iff $F$ is.

The $\operatorname{im}(F)$ case is not true without further assumptions. The image of such a vector bundle morphism may fail to restrict to a subspace on a single fiber. For instance, a morphism over the map from the 2-point discrete space to the singleton is a union of two subspaces.

Comment: Thank you for the answear.